# How to remove certain characters in a string without using replace or string.split() in python

Tags: python, string, replace, filenames

I am using a file name as a dictionary key.

```
key_dict = {employee_details.csv : ["name","address","phone"]}
```

This string is retrieved from S3 bucket in AWS.
Now the ETL produces the files with their version number added. "employee_details_0_0_0.csv"
The part "_0_0_0" of the string is a dynamic value which could change in future. say employee_details_1_2_3.csv.

How to get the file name correctly without the version added?

Input

```
input 1 : employee_details_0_0_0.csv
input 2 : employee_details_1_2_3.csv
```

Output

```
output 1 : employee_details.csv 
output 2 : employee_details.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `r"(_\d+){3}(?=\.csv)"` with  `""` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GSgOR2/1))

```py
>>> import re
>>> filename = "employee_details_0_0_0.csv"
>>> re.sub(r"(_\d+){3}(?=\.csv)", "", filename)
'employee_details.csv'
```

Regex explanation:

- `(...)` is a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- `_` matches literally an underscore
- `\d` is a [shortand character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) which matches a digit
- `{3}` repeats three times a certain pattern
- `(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), meaning "followed by..."
- `\.` is an escaped period and matches literally a period

Comment: (Really minor note..the capture group can also be a non capture group `(?:` as you don't need the last captured value from the iteration afterwards:-) )

Answer (score 1):

Considering the input string, we can assume that string parts representing the file names are alphabetical and versioning parts are numerical.
You may use the filter function, as well as the path to split the extension

```
from os import path    
def clear_name(recived_name:str)-> str:
    is_not_number = lambda string: not string.replace(".","").isnumeric()
    name , ext = path.splitext(recived_name)
    return "_".join(filter(is_not_number, name.split("_")) ) + ext
```

If you apply both inputs, the result will be

```
clear_name("employee_details_0_0_0.csv")
output: 'employee_details.csv'

clear_name("employee_details_1_2_3.csv")
output: 'employee_details.csv'
```

this function also remives floating numbers:

```
clear_name("employee_details_0.1.0.csv")
output:  'employee_details.csv'
```

if you wanted to see more about [os path look here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)
also, [filters docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)